# Android gps : how to check if a certain point has been reached?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app and I need to make sure that the device has reached a certain point described with lat and lon. The only thing that I can think of is to have something like that :

```
    Location initLoc = theManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double lat = initLoc.getLatitude();
    double lon = initLoc.getLongitude();
    MyPoint firstPoint = getPoints().get(0);

    double dist = CalcHelper.getDistance1(lat, lat, firstPoint.getLat(), firstPoint.getLon());

    while(dist > 30){

        initLoc = theManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        lat = initLoc.getLatitude();
        lon = initLoc.getLongitude();
        dist = CalcHelper.getDistance1(lat, lon, firstPoint.getLat(), firstPoint.getLon());

    }
```

But that causes the program to crash. I would be very appreciative if you could lead me to the right direction here.

Let me take the opportunity to ask a further question. As I said I am new to Android and GPS and having in mind there is little documentation and information on how to properly develop applications that work with GPS I am working in blind basically. So my question is:

This is how the onLocationChanged method looks like:

```
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lon = location.getLongitude();
            MyPoint firstPoint = MainScreen.dataset.getPoints().get(0);

            double dist = CalcHelper.getDistance1(lat, firstPoint.getLat(),lon, firstPoint.getLon());

            if(dist < 10){

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Start reached. Starting moving on track";
                int duration = 6000;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();   

            }else{

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Distance until start: "+dist;
                int duration = 6000;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

            }

    }
```

What I am trying to do is to make the program determine when I have reached the start of a track I have supplied as a set of points. So, when I start the program I receive a reasonable estimate on the distance. The problem is, when I start moving, the distance does not seem to be updated, it gets updated but after moving 50meters, it says i have only moved 5 say. On the other hand, when I start the application and I am less than 10m away from the starting point, it detects it properly. So basically, while I am moving with the device, the onLocationChanged method does not seem to give me the correct location that I am now on. Can you tell me what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: If you had a crash you can find useful information in the stack trace from your logcat. And for further error analysis we need that, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answers: mreichelt: actually it is not crashing, my bad, just stops responding and freezes. I think figured it out, basically, using a while() loop and requesting location update does not work. I just use an if statement in the onLocationChanged method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this it might be exactly what you're needing

[Proximity Alert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: That is brilliant ! How could I did not see it before. Will definitely help me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad i could help. If you flag a good answer as correct (click on the checkmark on the left side) your stackoverflow accept rating will go up and people are even more likely to help you. Welcome to stackoverflow ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is to make your activity implement LocationListener, i.e. subscribe to the GPS fix. E.g.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // request current location updates
        LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // set here the criteria for location provider accuracy
        Criteria locationProviderCriteria = new Criteria();
        locationProviderCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String locationProvider = locMan.getBestProvider(locationProviderCriteria, true);
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES_IN_MILLIS, MIN_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES_IN_METERS, this);
    }

    /*
     * This method will be called on each location update
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        //put here your logic to see whether the user reached the destination
    }
}
```